# Bootstrap 4 display property on landscape not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a nav side bar and I wish to hide the text and only show icons for iphone + ipad portrait and landscape but I cannot get the display property to work for landscape, only for portrait.

**HTML code**

```
<li class="sidenav_links">
                <a href="{% url 'evalsys:home' %}"><span class="fas fa-home"></span></a>
                <a class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-inline" href="{% url 'evalsys:home' %}">Opret evaluering</a>
            </li>
```

**Media queries**

```
/* iPhone 6, 7, 8 portrait */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px)
and (orientation: portrait)

/* iPhone 6, 7, 8 landsacpe */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 375px)
and (max-device-width : 667px)
and (orientation: landscape)

/* iPad Portrait Media Queries  */
 @media only screen
and (min-device-width: 768px)
and (min-device-height: 1024px)
and (orientation: portrait)

/* iPad Landscape Media Queries */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 1024px)
and (min-device-height: 768px)
and (orientation: landscape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only show icons for iphone + ipad portrait and landscape

```css
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .sidenav_links {
            background: #dddddd;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .fas .fa-home {
            display: none;
        }
        @media (max-width: 1366px) {
            .fas .fa-home {
                display: block;
            }
        }
```

```html
<li class="sidenav_links">
        <a href="{% url 'evalsys:home' %}"><span class="fas fa-home"></span></a>
        <a class="box" href="{% url 'evalsys:home' %}">Opret evaluering</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Ah right, so you've just made a media query and said display: none; when its ipad+iphone and display block when its above ipad width? Don't even need to use the display properties as a class then?